# Error With Post Request and Relationships Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails project where there is a Customer table and a Ticket table. The relationship is Ticket has_many :customers and Customer belongs_to :ticket.

On my Customer index page I list out all of the customers with create, update, and delete options. All of this works fine. However, what I am wanting to do now is create another button (on the index page for each customer) that when clicked, it creates a Ticket with the customer selected added to the ticket. I currently have the relationships setup in the models. My first idea was to make a add a button for each customer in the table and have that button make a post request to my create function in my Tickets controller like this

```
post 'tickets', to: 'tickets#create', as: 'create_ticket'
```

When the ticket function is invoked, I assumed that I would get the customer from the post request, create a new ticket, and somehow make the ticket take ownership of the customer with my relationship. 
Here is my create function.

```
def create
    @customer = Customer.find(params.require(:customer))
end
```

So far I have only been able to get errors like "ActionController::ParameterMissing in TicketsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: customer"

Here is the link in my index.html.erb that is making the post request

```
<%= link_to "add to tickets", create_ticket_path(c), method: :post %>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

---

I have just recently tried implementing this in a similar way to my edit function.

My link in the index.html.erb is now

```
<%= link_to "add to tickets", create_ticket_path(c) %>
```

My route is now

```
get 'tickets/:id/create', to: 'tickets#create', as: 'create_ticket'
```

When I click the button this is the url that my browser directs to

```
http://localhost:3000/tickets/1/create
```

and my create function in the Tickets controller is now

```
def create
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is the error I am now getting:

Template is missing
Missing template tickets/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/vagrant/ServiceManager/app/views" * "/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #46):

```
def find(*args)
    find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
end

def find_all(path, prefixes = [], *args)





<% @tickets.each do |t| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= t.description %></td>
        <td><%= t.customers.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here are my model associations:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :customers
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :ticket
end
```

Here is the content of the index.html.erb

Description:    Name:
                Customer

The name should be bob. It does the same thing for all customers.

Comment: Can you post the url that the `link_to` is generating? You aren't passing a json object with a `customer` key, which is why you are getting the error. Usually you would have a form with a customer['id] attribute that is a hidden field and then have the submit button be the button that is actually clicked or something of the sorts.

Comment: @CWitty I just edited the question. All of my edits are below the horizontal line.

Comment: So with that one, you aren't telling it to redirect or render anything so it is looking for a template which it doesnt find. Try a `redirect_to @customer` or soemthing and that should fix it

Comment: @CWitty Ok, that worked! I appreciate it. So, I still need to create the ticket. I followed a tutorial on how to make the associations, but I am still unsure of the code I need to actually create a ticket with a customer reference. Can you help here also?

Comment: Ill post in the answer field

Comment: It seems as if something is still wrong. When I open the index page for tickets, it loads all the tickets with the name of the customer as "Customer". When I try to access other attributes like email, it says email is undefined. I have added the index.html.erb to the bottom of the question. @CWitty

Comment: Because customers is an array of customers not a single one. You have to iterate over the list

Comment: wouldn't ATcustomer = Customer.find(params[:id]) load the single customer into ATcustomer and then with your code save correctly? @CWitty

Comment: I think you want to swap your association unless a customer can only ever have one ticket

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
@ticket = Ticket.new(customers: [@customer])
if @ticket.save
  redirect_to @ticket
else
  render :new # This can be a render or redirect or whatever should happen if it fails
end
```